# Get file mode in octal with stat (BSD vs GNU)

Tags: bash, gnu, stat, bsd

I am trying to get the file bits in octal, to assess whether a path is a regular file or a directory.

This works pretty well in `BSD` `stat` which is part of my `macOS`:

```sh
$ stat -f %Op /tmp/test.txt 
100644
```

How can I get the same (or similar) result in `stat` from `GNU`. The best I got is:

```sh
$ stat -c "%a" /tmp/test.txt
644
$ stat -c "%A" /tmp/test.txt
-rw-r--r--
```

Right now, the only way I am seeing is parsing the string result and check whether first character is `-` or is `d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU `stat` has the `%f` format code for this.  Unfortunately, it displays the raw mode in hex, so you have to use e.g. the shell's facilities to convert it.

Notice also that the format is specified with `-c`.

```
printf '%06o\n' 0x$(stat -c '%f' /tmp/test.txt)
```

For more details, refer to the [man page.](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html)

Comment: @KamilCuk what is the meaning of ```%06o``` ?

Comment: `printf` can display octal with `%o` and the `06` says to display six digits, zero padded from the left if required. The Bash manual page has a description of `printf` and its options, or you can review [its man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) too.

Comment: `stat -f %Op dir/` outputs `40755` so forcing a padding might not be ideal

Comment: Maybe take that out then. Just `%o` will display as many digits as required but no leading zeros.